# VPC内のLambdaはAPI Gatewayにアクセスできない？

Tags: aws-lambda, websocket, vpc, aws-api-gateway

現在関わっているプロジェクトでAPI Gateway(websocket)+Lambda＋RDS(RDS Proxy経由)の調査を行っていて、LambdaからRDS Proxy経由でデータベースへ接続するため、LambdaにVPCを設定したところ、Lambdaからのメッセージが返ってこなくなりました。

VPC内のLambdaからはAPI Gateway(websocket)経由のメッセージ返信はできなくなってしまうのでしょうか？

Lambdaからのメッセージ返信は以下のようにしてあります。言語はTypeScript

```
            const apiGateway = new ApiGatewayManagementApi({
                apiVersion: '2018-11-29',
                endpoint: event.requestContext.domainName + '/' + event.requestContext.stage
            });

            await apiGateway.postToConnection({
                ConnectionId: event.requestContext.connectionId,
                Data: 'data'
            } as ApiGatewayManagementApi.PostToConnectionRequest).promise();
```

LambdaにVPCを設定するまでは上記でメッセージを返すことができていました。

CloudWatchのログで確認してみたところ、`postToConnection` を呼んでいるあたりから処理が進んでおらず、タイムアウトになってしまっているようで、以下のようなログが出力されています。

```
2022-00-00T00:00:00.280Z 10xx0xx5-9821-4x02-8x05-1x588x7x460x Task timed out after 5.02 seconds
```

ネットワークはあまり詳しくなく、試しにセキュリティグループのインバウンド、アウトバウンドをすべてのトラフィックを通すような設定にしてみたり、サブネットにpublicとついたものを設定してみたりということを試していますが変わらずです。

対策方法などありましたらご教示いただかればと存じます。

構成に関してはお客様希望で、なるべくこの構成で開発ということになっています。

Answer (score 1):

ちょうど同じことが起こりました。私はVPC内のlambdaでRDSに接続してデータを取得した後、VPCを設定していないlambdaにデータを渡して実行させました。そのlambdaがWebSocket発信することで対応しています。
他に良い方法がありましたら、知りたいですね。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
思っていたより複雑で、これが良いやり方かはわかりませんが、以下のページのやり方でできるようです。

https://aws.amazon.com/jp/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/

Comment: websocket APIにカスタムドメインを追加することで対応できました！
endpointは「https://{カスタムドメイン}」です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。すぐには試せそうにないですが、今度試してみます。